# Semantic git message and cleaning

Tags: git, version-control

In one of my node code, I must do some cleaning. For example removing unused `console.log()` functions or comments placed here during dev/debugging phase by my coworker.

I try to follow some semantic git message rules, for cleaning, as mentioned [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/dev/git-commit-msg.html).

For example deleting useless console.log or debugging stuff like:

```
console.log('Starting app.js');
debugger;
```

**What kind of git message type should I use?** Certainly not `feat:` as it's not a new feature. I'd go maybe with `refactor:`.

Comment: This depends very heavily on things we can't know, like the culture of the people who'll be reading the git messages, what format they're normally in, etc. Mine are normally short sentences describing what I've done; things like "Added controller support to player input", "Removed debugging"; they don't have tags. Your project seems to have things like "refactor: Turned state-based global methods into OOP ones", or "feat: Controller vibration support". There's no single best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `chore`, since this will not change the way the "production" code work.

This is not a feature, not a bugfix, not a style change... so this is kind of a default choice, but it seems right.